# Execute and Confirm delete using SWAL and ajax on laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, sweetalert

when i click the button confirm on swal nothing happens, i dont khow if the problem is the ajax code
or somthing else
but when i delete the ajax code from the swal code it works fine and shows the sweetalert so i think the probleme comes from ajax

```
<script>
function deleteData(id) {
    swal({
            title: "Suppression",
            text: "Veuillez confirmer la suppression",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: "Confirmer",
            cancelButtonText: "Annuler",
            reverseButtons: true
        }.then(function () {
            var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
            $.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                url: "{{url('eventment/type')}}/" + id,
                data: {
                    _token: CSRF_TOKEN
                },
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (results) {

                    if (results.success === true) {
                        swal("Done!", results.message, "success");
                    } else {
                        swal("Error!", results.message, "error");
                    }
                } //success
            });
        })

    ) //swal
} //deleteData
</script>
```

Delete button

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteData({{$type->id}})" >Supprimer</button>
```

route file

```
Route::delete('eventment/type/{id}','TypeController@destroy')->name('type.destroy');
```

controller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $type = EventType::where('id', $id)->delete();

    return redirect()->to(route('admin.type.index'))->withFlashSucces('Le Type A Bien Etait Supprimé');
}
```

Comment: change $type = EventType::where('id', $id)->delete(); to  $type=EventType::find($id); $type->delete();

Comment: same problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without ajax.first your button  make it as a form

```
<form id="del_event" action="{{ route('type.destroy',$type->id) }}" method="post"style="display: inline;">
{!! method_field('delete') !!}
{{ csrf_field() }}
 <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" id="del_id">Supprimer</button>

</form
```

Button has a id "del_id" when it click call a function below there

```
<script>
        $("#del_id").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            swal({
                title: "Suppression",
            text: "Veuillez confirmer la suppression",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: "Confirmer",
            cancelButtonText: "Annuler",
            }).then((result) => {
                if(result) {
                    $("#del_event").submit();
                }
            }
        )
            ;
        });
    </script>
```

Your destroy function

```
 $type=EventType::find($id);
 $type->delete();``
```

Comment: its working but when i click on the delete button there's no confirm alert

Comment: i edit my answer.please check again. before a space in "= >" to " =>" need to no space